# Minimization of uncertainty principle for infinite parabolic well (quantum harmonic oscillator)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I've recently had a lecture on how to minimize the uncertainty principle in infinite parabolic well. The analytical solution for $\psi_n$ is
$$\psi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}2^nx_0n!}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2x_0^2}}H_n(\frac{x}{x_0})$$
where $H_n$ is a Hermite polynomial.

Take $\xi=\frac{x}{x_0}$ where $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}$, then it becomes
$$\psi_n(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}2^nn!}}e^{\frac{-\xi^2}{2}}H_n(\xi)$$

So now the uncertainty principle is
$$\delta \hat{x} \delta \hat{p_x}=\sqrt{\biggl<{(\Delta\hat{x})^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}\biggl<(\Delta\hat{p_x})^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}}}$$
where
$$\biggl<(\Delta\hat{x})^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}=\biggl<\hat{x}^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}-\biggl<\hat{x}\biggr>_{\psi_n}^2$$

$$\biggl<(\Delta\hat{p_x})^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}=\biggl<\hat{p_x}^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}-\biggl<\hat{p_x}\biggr>_{\psi_n}^2$$

Now we have to calculate each of these averages. I have no problem with that except with $\biggl<\hat{p_x}^2\biggr>_{\psi_n}$. On the lecture we were given the following calculations:
[image]

In the end I get a different result which is
$$=-\frac{\hbar^2}{x_0^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\pi}2^nn!}}(-\frac{1}{2})\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\xi^2}H_n(\xi)H_n(\xi)d\xi$$

I'm missing the $-n$ that later is essential to obtain correct energy states $E_n=\hbar\omega(n+\frac{1}{2})$.

I've revisited the calculations about 4 times and still get the wrong result. I don't know what's happening.

During calculations we use the following properies of a Hermite polynomial:
[image]

Comment: An alternative for computing the expectation value of $p^2$ is using the quantum version of the virial theorem [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#In_quantum_mechanics) to conclude that for the quantum harmonic oscillator and an a stationary state, the expectation value of the kinetic part of the hamiltonian is equal to to the expectation value of the potential. This means that the expectation value of the kinetic term is half the energy of the state: $\frac{1}{2m}\langle p^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \hbar \omega \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)$.

Comment: While I really appreciate your help (that's a really nice way to avoid all the calculations), I would really like to know what's wrong with the derivation from the lecture.